# Assembly error after splitting solution into different projects

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

So, I had a ASP.NET MVC application, but everything was in 1 project. (ugh)
I decided to get a little closer to how it's done in the field, and split up into different projects in one solution.

After doing so, I spent some time adding all the needed assemblies to my new DataAccess project, adding it as a dependency to the other project etc. To have it not run and throw the error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

So clearly something was wrong with the MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 reference.
I spent hours searching for a solution, from `changing the versions in my web.config` to completely `deinstall and reinstall the dependency`, but no matter what I did, the error was here to stay.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried what I've tried (no matter the reference you're stuck with) It might be a good idea to check if it's been referenced in any other project in your solution.

If so, delete the reference from the other project (not the DataAccess project). And make sure you have the right versions in your web.config. You can check the versions via properties in VS.

When I did that, everything suddenly worked just fine.